# berks upload skipping the cookbook recipe

Tags: berkshelf

I wrote the recipe and trying to upload in chef server. While running a command `berks upload` got this [image: output]

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is "this issue"? Please share your code and outputs in text form, not as images

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

By default, you should change version number with each berks upload, if you want to upload same version add `--force` flag to the command.

Comment: Thank you very much sir @szymon

Comment: if you specify recipe versions in environment files, you could use **berks upload <cookbook> --no-freeze** when uploading a newer cookbook for testing without changing the version multiple times for testing, and then upload again w/o the **--no-freeze** once it is ready for your production environment.